# 'Parameter "self" unfilled' error in PyCharm when attempting to access method in another class

Tags: python, class, methods, syntax, pycharm

I am using PyCharm. I keep getting this error "Parameter self unfilled" on all my of method calls to methods in other classes and I can't for the life of me figure it out. In this particular instance, it actually says "Parameter final_formatted_filename unfilled" because it's taking that argument as the self argument. What am I missing?

FileHandler.py

```
from LogHandler import LogHandler
import Main


class FileHandler:

      def format_file_name_output(self, owner_name):
          date_and_time = self.main.Main.date_and_time_snapshot()
          final_formatted_filename = (owner_name + " (" + date_and_time[0] + "_" + date_and_time[1] + ")")
          LogHandler.create_new_log(final_formatted_filename)
```

LogHandler.py

```
class LogHandler:

    def __init__(self, log_file):
        self.log_file = log_file

    def create_new_log(self, final_formatted_filename):
        self.log_file = open(final_formatted_filename + " Log.txt", 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
```

The last parenthesis in the last line of FileHandler.py is what is highlighted with the aforementioned error: "Parameter final_formatted_filename unfilled". My code is riddled with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Methods should be called on *instances*. You are calling them on *classes*. In the call `LogHandler.create_new_log(final_formatted_filename)`, what do you think is filled in for the `self` parameter? Are you aware of the basics of OOP in Python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `LogHandler` then you can call the method `create_new_log` on the instance.

```
handler = LogHandler()
handler.create_new_log(final_formatted_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well thhbbbbb. I swear in all the different things I tried, I had tried this and it did not work. But now it does seem to be solved. Thanks again for your help.